# How do you share an expensive component between pages in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular app that shares a table component on several distinct pages. Fetching data for the table is an expensive operation, so I'd like to reuse the same table on different pages. Furthermore, the table is placed differently in each page, so having the table as a part of a common layout is unfortunately not possible.

Here's a few simplified pages.

full-view-page.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: `full-page`,
  template:
`
<h1>Accounts Table</h1>
<expensive-table></expensive-table>
`.
)}
```

accounts-page.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'accounts-page',
  template: 
`
<h1>Accounts</h1>
<expensive-table></expensive-table>
<form *ngIf="account">
  // Form content here
</form>
`,
  styles: [// Some styles here...]
})
```

charts-page.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'charts-page',
  template: 
`
<h1>Charts</h1>
<analysis-charts></analysis-charts>
<expensive-table></expensive-table>
<recommendation></recommendation>
`,
  styles: [// Some styles here...]
})
```

Ideally, Angular only loads the component `expensive-table` only once and builds "around" the component so that the state of the component (current search, scrollbar, filters) is always the same. Right now, I see a separate table being loaded for each page.

Comment: Just keep the data in the service + persist component state.

Comment: Ideally you want to separate re-useable ui table and data-access (via service). Since data-access service is a singleton and both tables get data via dependency injection the data (if persisted) is shared